# Import multiple text files and their titles into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a folder with around 10.000 text files. I would like to import these files into a MySQL table with two columns. For each row, I would like to have the title of the text file (e.g. 1234.txt) in one column, and the content of the file in another column. I can use PHP. How would you advise me to do that?

Comment: Generally I would advise keeping files on the filesystem instead of in a database

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I need to process the text with a script that is only available to me on MySQL. So I need to find a way to import the files.

Comment: Some clarification is required here. First, what's the length of your largest text file? You need to know this to be able to choose the appropriate data type, e.g `VARCHAR(255)`, `TEXT`, `MEDIUMTEXT`, etc.  Second, how does your "script" use this table? Does it use `FULLTEXT` searching? Does it require an index on the text column? Third, is your text recorded in ASCII, Latin-1, UTF-8, or what?

Comment: I don't think you can do that using MySQL only. Can you use a scripting language such as PHP? I tried doing it in bash but I gave up (escaping is the issue).

Comment: @OllieJones: The largest file is 3K characters. I need an index on the text column.I don't know what the encoding is.

Comment: @RandomSeed I can use PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following, the below code will go through all the text files in a directory and add the filename of each file as the Title and the content as Content to a MySQL database.

```
<?php
$size = "";
//Change "MyFolder" with the path and name of the directory where the .txt files are located.
$dir = "MyFolder";

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;

        $myFile = "$dir/$file";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');

        $size = filesize($myFile);
        if ($size > 0) {
        $content = fread($fh, $size);

        $title = $file; 
        echo $title."</br>";
        }

        $con=mysqli_connect("HostName","Username","Password","Database");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }     
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table_name (Title, Content) VALUES ('$title', '$content')");

        mysqli_close($con);  

        fclose($fh);
    }
closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I just tested it and it does not seem to work. Would you have an idea why? No error, no nothing, it just does not load anything in the table. The folder "myfolder" with all of the text documents is in the same folder as the php script.

Comment: My bad, it was a directory problem. It worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, it might not be the best solution but I hope it helps.

Comment: It really does! However, I have a quick question for you. I have 8K text files in the folder. I added an echo $title; in the script so that I could make sure that all documents are imported. Weirdly enough, all names are displayed as imported but 2K rows are missing in the database. I tried twice. Any idea?

Comment: OK, no problem. I will take a look through the code and will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could (ab)use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to load an entire file in a column. The "trick" is just to provide a sequence of characters that is not present in the file as line/field termination:

```
mysql> create table tbl(fname CHAR(255), data TEXT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)


mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/demo.txt' INTO TABLE tbl 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'XXX' LINES TERMINATED BY 'YYY' 
            (data) SET fname = 'demo.csv';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from tbl;
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| fname    | data                                                                                             |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| demo.csv | Date, Amount, Name
2013-01-01, 1000, "Apple"
2013-01-02, 500, "Orange"
2013-01-03, 250, "Prune"
 |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If order to load all the files in a folder, you will have to call that statement from a loop in your host language You could even do that with a simple shell script:

```
for i in *.txt; do 
  echo "LOAD DATA INFILE '$i' INTO TABLE tbl 
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'XXX' LINES TERMINATED BY 'YYY' 
                (data) SET fname = '$i';";
  done
  | mysql -p -u user_name -h host_name db_name
```